# set value for first tab in tabbar after segue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

I have the following situation.
[image]

Like you see I have a segue that goes to the tabbarController. But I need to set an id in de VC that is pointed on the screen. Have you guys any idea how I can achieve this.

Normally you would use this code.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showTab"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setPersonId:personobject.cu_id];
    }
}
```

But this goes to my tabbarController and not to my FirstTabController. Any help?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Your destination view controller is a `UITabBarController`. You'll have to get an instance from that tab controller to the controller in the first tab.

```
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *) segue.destinationViewController;
FirstTabController *firstController = [tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

[firstController setPersonId:personobject.cu_id];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would probably have worked. But I fixed it at a cleaner way. I saved the Id just in my NSUserDefaults, because I am gonna need it also in other VC. But still thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Oké,

I fixed my problem by just saving my personId into NSUserDefaults at the following way.

```
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                             [prefs setInteger:[personObject.cu_id intValue] forKey:@"personId"];
                             [prefs synchronize];
```

Now I can get access to it in every VC by calling the following.

```
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    _personId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[prefs integerForKey:@"personId"]];
```